# Displaying video frame by frame

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

What is the simplest way to access a video's individual frame rate, be able to step through a video's frames, and set up some sort of frame buffer to pre-load subsequent frames with a video player made in WPF? I am aware of DirectShow, but it seems to be more useful for people who want to modify the frames of the video. I just want to be able to step through a video frame by frame, navigate to a specific frame, and normalize the frame rates of multiple videos playing at once (for example, three videos with 10 fps, 20 fps, and 30 fps respectively would play simultaneously at 10 fps).

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an easy problem actually.  I would recommend using an available directshow filter to read the file data, pass it to a decompressor filter (since your video I'm assuming isn't a raw format like YUV), chained to a sample grabber.

The sample grabber will give you the decompressed raw images and you can use the Image class to get JPEGS to show.

To synchronize the frames based on framerate, when you capture the sample frame you can get the presentation time for that particular timestamp. This is how you'll be able to synchronize your videos regardless of framerate.  The presentation time is a timestamp that indicates when that frame is supposed to be displayed.  Each video will give you a different one and you can determine who should be displayed when based on that.

As far as caching goes you can seek on some of the decoder filters. The MPEG2 decoder that comes with windows exposes an

```
IMediaSeeking
```

pin which you should be able to call back to and tell it to seek to a new time.

I would suggest using something like graphedit to test your filter construction